# Change div position ontouchdrag (if such an event is usable)

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Basically, I have a web page which is a div inside a div. Let's say that div 1 (the container) is 500px high. Div 2 is 100px high inside of that container. What I want to do is detect the user touching div 2 on the screen (this is a web page on a mobile phone) and as they drag up/down, the div moves with them. I've done some research and have seen this being done using matrix3d and transform y in CSS 3 (but I can't find a good explanation for someone with little experience with this sort of thing such as myself). I want it so that, let's say, the user drags the second div to the bottom and some of the content goes outside of the container div. I don't want it to scroll down, I do want it to disappear... BUT I want it to kind of 'bounce' back into view. So here's the breakdown.

- user presses the screen
- user drags div 2 which is inside of div 1. As they drag the div, it moves in the direction of their drag.
- the user can drag the div right to the top/bottom. If they drag it outside of the container div, that's fine. The container div should not resize or become scrollable and part of div 2 should disappear from view.
- when the user releases the drag, the div should bounce back into position. Let's say, if it is dragged too high up, it bounces back to position 100, 100. If it's dragged too far down then it bounces back to 100, 500 (I figure the bounce can be controlled by a CSS transition).

So, does anyone have an example that I can look at to see this in action or a tutorial that will help me understand how I can achieve this? I apologise for not providing any code as a basis to start from, but in truth, I don't really know where to start myself.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Show us the code, you are struggling with!

Comment: Well herein lies my problem, I don't really know what to try/where to start. If there's something that you could provide to kick start me with this problem I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safari dev docs are your friend:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Checkout the the touch move section for moving a div, for your case you want to set conditionals for if the user goes outside the bounds of your outer div, and disable scrolling using overflow hidden.